Strawberry Music Player no longer starts
$ strawberry
17:50:33.254 INFO  main:165    Strawberry is already running - activating existing window (1)
17:50:38.256 WARN  unknown     Connection timed out 
17:50:38.256 ERROR main:168    Could not send message to primary instance.

For some reason strawberry thinks that there is an instance running and times out connecting to it - because there is nothing running.
Trying to start as root works (but no sound and running as root is not a solution anyway).
All files related to strawberry have already been purged, including strawberry itself, but the error persists after a fresh install.
$ strawberry --version
Strawberry 1.0.23

$ pgrep -f strawberry
(no output)

$ ps aux | grep '[s]trawberry'
(no output)

$ cat /etc/os-release command
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="21.2 (Victoria)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 21.2"
VERSION_ID="21.2"
VERSION_CODENAME=victoria
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

I found this error message in the code, but it hasn't helped me to solve this problem.
https://github.com/strawberrymusicplayer/strawberry/blob/master/src/main.cpp
CommandlineOptions options(argc, argv);
  {
    // Only start a core application now, so we can check if there's another instance without requiring an X server.
    // This MUST be done before parsing the commandline options so QTextCodec gets the right system locale for filenames.
    QCoreApplication core_app(argc, argv);
    KDSingleApplication single_app(QCoreApplication::applicationName(), KDSingleApplication::Option::IncludeUsernameInSocketName);
    // Parse commandline options - need to do this before starting the full QApplication, so it works without an X server
    if (!options.Parse()) return 1;
    logging::SetLevels(options.log_levels());
    if (!single_app.isPrimaryInstance()) {
      if (options.is_empty()) {
        qLog(Info) << "Strawberry is already running - activating existing window (1)";
      }
      if (!single_app.sendMessage(options.Serialize())) {
        qLog(Error) << "Could not send message to primary instance.";
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }


Please [edit] your question and add your operating system. Also show us the output of pgrep -f strawberry or ps aux | grep '[s]trawberry to make sure there isn't actually a hung instance somewhere. Does this persist after rebooting?

@terdon I added in the OS, neither of these commands produced any output, since there is no strawberry process running.

As suspected Strawberry puts a lock file somewhere and that lock file isn't put under /home/.
It is put under /tmp/.
Removing the two files...
/tmp/kdsingleapp-username-strawberry  
/tmp/kdsingleapp-username-strawberry.lock  

...solved this issue.
